# Google Chrome Apps: chrome.storage.local

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-app

I am having a struggle finding out why the following is happening in a application i'm developing:

So i read a JSON file where i want to read and save his content on localStorage, which in a chrome app is chrome.storage.local

So i get the following from a json file:

```
{
  "schedule": {
    "id": "416a18d6-7e42-4f8a-ac24-e902abe76f39",
    "name": "blabla",
    "updatedOn": "2013-09-08T16:34:41.000Z",
    "etag": "esxrdctfvygbuhnij5464df7g8hu",
    "applications": [
      {
        "id": "app001",
        "type": "text/html",
        "src": "http://www.google.com"
      },
      {
        "id": "app002",
        "type": "text/html",
        "src": "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
      }
    ],
    "normalContent": [
      {
        "layout_id": "layout001",
        "layout_name": "layout1",
        "layout_dur": "indefinite",
        "regions": [
          {
            "region_id": "region001",
            "region_name": "regiao1",
            "left": "0",
            "top": "0",
            "width": "0.5",
            "height": "1",
            "minWidth": "0",
            "minHeight": "0",
            "scheduleItem": "container",
            "limitCycle": "1",
            "selector": "seq",
            "containerList": [
              {
                "cid": "app001",
                "dur": "25"
              },
              {
                "cid": "app002",
                "dur": "15"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "region_id": "region002",
            "region_name": "regiao2",
            "left": "0.5",
            "top": "0",
            "width": "0.5",
            "height": "1",
            "minWidth": "0",
            "minHeight": "0",
            "scheduleItem": "container",
            "limitCycle": "1",
            "selector": "seq",
            "containerList": [
              {
                "cid": "app002",
                "dur": "15"
              },
              {
                "cid": "app001",
                "dur": "15"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So i get this and then i save the content in storage using:

```
chrome.storage.local.set({playerSchedule:this.schedule}, function(){
    console.log('saved!')       
});
```

Later on when i read the content stored using:

```
chrome.storage.local.get(["playerSchedule", "playerScheduleType"], function (res) {
    self.currentSchedule = res.playerSchedule;
    self.scheduleType = res.playerScheduleType;
});
```

This is what i get:

```
{
  "schedule": {
    "applications": [
      {
        "id": "app001",
        "type": "text/html",
        "src": "http://www.google.com"
      },
      {
        "id": "app002",
        "type": "text/html",
        "src": "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
      }
    ],
    "etag": "esxrdctfvygbuhnij5464df7g8hu",
    "id": "416a18d6-7e42-4f8a-ac24-e902abe76f39",
    "name": "blabla",
    "normalContent": [
      {
        "layout_dur": "indefinite",
        "layout_id": "layout001",
        "layout_name": "layout1",       
        "regions": [
          {
            ...
            "containerList": [
            ]
          },
          {
            ...
            "containerList": [
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "updatedOn": "2013-09-08T16:34:41.000Z"    
  }
}
```

As you can observe, the content i read comes in alphabetic order and the content in containerList is empty. Any reason why this is happening? I solved this by converting the object to string and storing it, but i wonder why saving as object i get that from reading as an object or is there something i am missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The alphabetically ordering is standards-compliant. The properties of a JavaScript object are not ordered, so they may be rearranged in any order. Not sure why the contents of `containerList` are vanishing, though.

Comment: FWIW I did a JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(stuff in your first sample)) and it came out clean. ("clean" == containerList stuff still there.)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=277647. Fix is in the works for Chrome 31.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to have identified correctly the issue. However, answers on Stack Overflow should be more than a link and should stand on their own. Please [edit] your answer to contain more information about the specific nature of the bug -- namely, that `chrome.storage` seems to only accept 10 levels of object nesting. Once you do, I will happily upvote your answer.